# Some actions with object in UpdateAPIView when update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My code:

```
class CarView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = CarSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ...

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # some actions
        return super(CarView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In update method I want to do some operations with updated object. How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) and [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it with self.get_object()

Take a look at the source UpdateView, which you are overriding. You can use the same method to get the object:

```
class UpdateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Update a model instance.
    """
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the `perform_update` method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) which is available on views and is used to perform the update on the serializer. It is designed to be a hook that is triggered when the serializer needs to be saved (which performs the update), and it must call `serializer.save()` in order to do the update.

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    # get the object itself
    instance = self.get_object()
    # modify fields during the update
    modified_instance = serializer.save(model_field=new_value)
```

You can pass attributes that should be updated on the model in the `save` method on the serializer. It is not recommended to interact directly with the instance unless you are using the one returned from `serializer.save()`, which will contain any updated fields on the model.